# Swift - why NSColor becomes lighter when rendered

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscolor

I've created NSWindow and made it's background colour absolutely blue (#0000FF). But when the window is rendered, the colour is "lighter" than it should be (#0F3FFB).

```
class LilWindow: NSViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.window?.backgroundColor = 
             NSColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)


}
```

Does anyone know why it is happening and how to fix this? (screenshot attached)

[image]

Comment: Try `NSColor.init(calibratedRed:green:blue:alpha:)` instead.

Comment: @KenThomases nope, still same result

Comment: It's clear the colors are different, but how exactly did you determine their values? Is that mechanism color-profile-aware? What profile is it saying it has measured relative to? (Color values are actually meaningless except relative to a profile.) Also, what did you use to produce the (supposedly) correct background?

Comment: Background produced by googling "#0000ff", used photoshop's color picker.
Not sure what you mean by "profile aware", @KenThomases?

Comment: What color profile did Photoshop say the color values were relative to? Also, did Photoshop agree that the background is #0000ff? (If Photoshop is actually representing the color as "#<six hex digits>", then it's almost certainly in sRGB color profile. In that case, you could try `NSColor.init(SRGBRed:green:blue:alpha:)`.)

Comment: I neglected to suggest the most obvious approach if you really just want blue: use `NSColor.blueColor()`. Regarding color profiles: it's similar to how text is represented in computers. The number `0x65` is just a number and doesn't mean anything about a text character until it is interpreted relative to an encoding like ASCII or UTF-8, at which point it represents the character 'e'. Providing numbers for red, green, and blue is not enough to specify a color. The numbers have to interpreted relative to a profile to become colors. Each `NSColor` method interprets the numbers differently.

Comment: If you launch Text Edit and then select Format > Font > Show Colors, it will bring up OS X's standard color picker. If you use the eye dropper widget on the Color Sliders tab to select a color, it will fill in the values. But you have to click the gear icon next to the pop-up menu to see which color profile those values are relative to. You can also select a different profile to have the color values converted to be relative to that profile. I'm not familiar with Photoshop, but it should provide some similar information and control.

Comment: cool, i think it is rgb, i tried `init(SRGBRed)` and `init(calibratedRed)` as well as tried every colorSpace available and still i cannot achieve clear colors.

Comment: thanks i tried blueColor() before posting the question (and it is lighter than a proper blue), but i need all colors to be correctly represented in the app, ty.
By "proper blue" i mean the r:0, g:0, b:255 color that looks the same in browser as well as every tool i managed to find shows 0:0:255 (or #0000FF).

Comment: Is there any chance that you've set the window's `colorSpace` property? Did you set the view's `alphaValue`? Is there anything else custom about your view hierarchy or window? Can you reproduce this in a new project?

Comment: @KenThomases that's exactly what i did for a question, the code upper is literally the whole project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a couple of hours fiddling with code and @KenThomases help, I figured out that if you want your RGB colours to looks correctly on `NSImages` and `NSWindows`, you must convert it into `NSDeviceRGBColorSpace` colorspace. To do this I've written a simple function:

```
func toScreenColor(color:NSColor) -> NSColor {
  var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0

  color
  .colorUsingColorSpaceName(NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace)!
  .getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

  return NSColor(deviceRed: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
}
```